# Want to redirect after first statment finish execution in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have below code

```
redirecTo = () => {
  this.props.removeLine(); // api call 
  Window.location.href = '';
}
```

When I'm calling the above method api call is getting cancelled and href is executing.

I want to redirect once above api call finishes execution.

Comment: Well, how does your API call look? You need to wait for the API call to finish and then redirect

Comment: By the way, are you really trying to redirect with `Window.location.href`? I mean, with capital `W`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function inside `removeLine` function that will be executed only if it is passed. So `removeLine` function has to accept a prop like:

```
removeLine(callback)
```

and later on in the end of `removeLine` function you have to check if it was passed and execute it so add it in the end:

```
   if(callback){
     callback()
   }
```

so now if you use `removeLine` function somewhere if you want it to do some additional things you just use it like that:

```
redirecTo = () => {
   this.props.removeLine(Window.location.href = '');
}
```

By that it will only redirect when you pass `Window.location.href` inside it. Otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: but wait @valli, why don't you just put Window.location.href = ''; inside removeLine() function? in the end?

Comment: Yes,we can do that but I don't want to do it in api call 'cause that might be used in many places where redirection is not needed.